# MS-Word, Hidden text always shows after opening

Tags: ms-word

Hidden text doesn't behave as I would expect: I have a document with some text marked hidden. If I then set ShowHiddenText false either via File-Options-Display-HiddenText or programmatically

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = False
```

the text is hidden.
BUT: If I save the document and then reopen it, the hidden text is again vissible. This behavior defies much/most of the purpose of hidden text. What am I overlooking?
This happens for both docx and docm formats.

Comment: You are right that this is not normal behavior. I am assuming that the hidden text is not XE fields. Does this happen if you are operating Word in safe mode? https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72  Display of hidden text is an application option, not a document setting.

Comment: Yes, when starting Word in safe mode and then opening a docx that has hidden text, the hidden text is shown. You are right - I'm not talking about XE codes, but simple text for which I have activated 'Hidden' via the Font dialog box next to 'strikethrough', 'superscript', etc.

Comment: Hi, I just noticed that this was in SO. This is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others.

Answer (score 0):

### Try changing the option.

File > Options

[image: options dialog]